# Twilio number as voicemail - receive forwarding number as callerid

Tags: twilio, voice, twilio-twiml, caller-id

I am building an application where a user will call our clients personal phonenumber. His voicemail is set one of our Twilio numbers.
Is there a way to find out which client forwarded the call to us?

I am using a TwiML app with our API as webhook.
I successfully receive the calls and see the phonenumber of the caller as 'from' and 'caller' and our 'twilio' number as 'to'.

Since it is a forwarded call I would expect the 'caller' should be the clients number, 'from' the caller and 'to' our twilio number, or at least both 'caller' and 'from' should be the client rather than the original caller. However, both 'from' and 'caller' are always the number of the original caller.

Comment: By "His voicemail is set one of our Twilio numbers" do you mean the "client'[s personal phonenumber" will forward the call to Twilio in order to leave a voicemail? If so, the "client's personal phonenumber" is probably changing the caller id back to the original caller and not maintaining the "client's personal phonenumber".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to provision a phone number for each client. That way each client will forward calls into a unique phone number that only they use. If you have 10 clients you will have 10 Twilio phone numbers. Each of those provisioned numbers will use your same TwiML app w/ API as webhook. This is described in this ["How to Build a Call Tracking Solution"](https://www.twilio.com/use-cases/call-and-text-marketing/call-tracking/build).

Comment: Actually this is what I was trying to avoid as I have to buy a number for each client. However, it seems to be the only possible solution. Some providers pass a parameter "ForwardedFrom" which would be what I was looking for, but unfortunately not all do and therefore it is not a safe solution.

Comment: You should try using the [callerId attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial) of the Dial verb. But, if what you want is both the original caller's ANI and the person who forwarded the call's ANI then I don't think you can get both at the same time.